# Access to LibreOffice's Compare Documents using python

Tags: python, csv, diff, libreoffice

I have two .csv files that I want to use LibreOffice's compare documents tool (Edit>Compare Document) with.

These csv files are made after the run of a long and involved script, and it would be nice to be able to have the compare process to be automatic as well, with the result being a *window* of LibreOffice open with the changes as if I selected compare manually. I want the specific LibreOffice gui (which I believe does a great job highlighting differences) not just a diff.

Looking online, it seems like there is nice but limited set of python wrappers for libre office ([pyoo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyoo)).

However, despite [related](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libreoffice-bugs/2015-September/299341.html) [questions](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/35036/is-there-a-comprehensive-command-line-diff-tool-for-libreoffice-documents/), I couldn't see any way of gaining access to the compare functionality through this or any other library. **Is the Compare Documents functionality available at the python level, the UNO API level, or simply not available at all?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [dispatcher](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/2/26/OOME_3_0_11.The_Dispatcher.odt):

```java
Dispatcher.executeDispatch(
    (XDispatchProvider)Frame, ".uno:CompareDocuments", "", 0, propertyValueFile);
```

A complete Java example is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=2795.